# TYPO3 CONTENT select pass Argument to USER/USER_INT

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-9.x

typoscript:

```
lib.category = CONTENT
lib.category {
  table=sys_category
  select {
    pidInList = root
    selectFields = sys_category.*
    join = sys_category_record_mm ON sys_category_record_mm.uid_local = sys_category.uid
    where.field = sys_category_record_mm.uid_foreign = data.uid
    languageField = 0
  }
  renderObj = USER_INT
  renderObj {
    userFunc = InstantAitExt\AitContacts\GetPageCategories->testExecute
    alias = TEXT
    alias.value = data.uid
  }
}
```

so i have to pass 1-x arguments to testExecute. one of those parameters should hold the uid of a given page. this uid gets passed to lib.category=CONTENT via

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.category" data="{page}" />
```

so `data.uid` is basically `page.data.uid`

thing is if i pass `data.uid` to `alias.value` the argument holds "data.uid" as a string and not the actual value i need.

so how is it possible to pass the actual pageId to alias.value

also, the query works but i am not able to verify/debug

```
where.field = sys_category_record_mm.uid_foreign = data.uid
```

to check if the query really gets the correct value (page id from view)

help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't debug it as it is an syntax error.

the attribute is `where` and if you use `where.field` you want to set the value from a field (of current context). after the equal sign the name of a field is expected.

But you give an expression `sys_category_record_mm.uid_foreign = data.uid`. That can't be evaluated.

What you want is an expression with a data. this data should be replaced.
So you either use a wrap for the replaced data (or field)

```
where.data = data.uid
where.wrap = sys_category_record_mm.uid_foreign = |
```

which is equal to

```
where.field= uid
where.wrap = sys_category_record_mm.uid_foreign = |
```

as `data` is the current context, so you can access the field directly.

or you use an `insertData`:

```
where = sys_category_record_mm.uid_foreign = {data.uid}
where.insertData = 1
```

---

EDIT:

if you only want to submit the page uid to the typoscript viewhelper you can use
`<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.category" data="{page.uid}" />` or a simple array like:
`<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.category" data="{uid:page.uid}" />`

while the second call would not change the typoscript above (you only have a smaller `data` array which contains only the field `uid` while the original call contains the whole pages record).

For the viewhelper with just the uid value you have to use `current`:

```
where = current
where.wrap = sys_category_record_mm.uid_foreign = |
```

Comment: thanks, gonna look into that.  could you also tell me how i would access the passed argument if i just pass a single value like <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.category" data="{page.data.uid}" /> ?  what would the where.data = xx look like?

Comment: answer enhanced

Comment: thanks again, please mention in your answer if its possible to pass the data.uid/uid/current to the renderObj = USER_INT part.  is the passed value available within that block? so i can checkmark your answer

Comment: in the `renderObj` you have another context. The context is the current (joined) record. as you have the join condition `sys_category_record_mm.uid_foreign = data.uid` you could use that field for access to `data.uid`.